# Call meteor method while another is executing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two buttons that are intended to act as a "start" and "stop" that fire off methods on the back end when clicked. EG:

```
{{#if isExecuting}}
  {{>CylonButton method="stop"}}
{{else}}
  {{>CylonButton method="start"}}
{{/if}}
```

The meteor methods look as follows.

```
Meteor.methods({
  start: function (data) {
    Cylon.downloadData(data); // chunks data and downloads it, could take a while
    this.unblock();           // now that it's ready, it can be unblocked.
    Cylon.load();             // do this longer running method.
  },
  stop: function () {
    Cylon.stop();             // stop the method. This should _always_ be available
  }
});
```

However, I can't call `stop` until the other method unblocks. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

`this.unblock` allows subsequent method calls to execute before the previous one finished. Sounds like you want to move it to the first line right when the function begins

Comment: Because I don't want _other_ meteor methods to be able to be called, only `stop`